# order of ligature in metafont

Tags: fonts, ligatures, metafont

How are ambiguities in ligature resolved by metafont ? Say I have

```
ligtable letter1 : letter2 =: letter12;
ligtable letter2 : letter3 =: letter23;
```

If a sequence "letter1 letter2 letter3" appears, will the ligature happen for the first two and not the last two as the letter1:letter2 ligature appears first in the kerning/ligature file ?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no ambiguity: after changing `letter1 letter2` into `letter12`, no ligature will be attempted between `letter12` and `letter3`, unless an entry for it is present in the ligature table. It's the standard case for `ffi`

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. Was looking for confirmation.